# R: Using pipe %>% and pkg::fo leads to error "Error in .::base : unused argument"

Tags: r, pipe, tidyverse, magrittr

I am using `magrittr`'s pipe %>%, followed immediately by a function called by: package::function, and get the error: **Error in .::base : unused argument (mean)**

What is the problem?

```r
library(magrittr)
c(1,2) %>%
  base::mean
#> Error in .::base: unused argument (mean)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's happening is that magrittr is getting confused as to exactly what function you want to insert the previous value into. When you do just

```
c(1,2) %>%
  mean
```

`magrittr` is able to easily see that `mean` is a symbol that points to the mean function. But when you do `base::mean`, things get a bit trickier because `::` is also a function in R. Let's compare the difference between `base::mean` and `base::mean()` in R in terms of how they are translated into function calls.

```
as.list(quote(base::mean))
# [[1]]
# `::`    
# [[2]]
# base    
# [[3]]
# mean

as.list(quote(base::mean()))
#  [[1]]
# base::mean
```

You can see these parse differently. When you just type `base::mean` R will see the `::` function first and will try to pass in the numbers there. Basically to's trying to call

```
`::`(., base, mean)
```

which doesn't make sense can that's what gives you that specific error message

But if you explicitly add the `()`, R can see that you are trying to call the function returned from `base::mean` so it will add the parameter to the right place. So you can do

```
c(1,2) %>%
  base::mean()
```

or

```
c(1,2) %>%
    (base::mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is a version of `magrittr` that does not have this issue but it hasn't been pushed to CRAN for a very long time now.

As documented in [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues/78) issue, github version of magrittr pipes can successfully deal with

```r
c(1,2) %>%
    base::mean
```

```
[1] 1.5
```

This was fixed 4 years ago but never made it to CRAN. Since most people would be using the CRAN version, I would not suggest writing code that depends on this fix.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you call the function with a further argument, it won't work. Simple solution is to use `(.)`, i.e. `base::mean(.)`:

```r
library(magrittr)
c(1,2) %>%
  base::mean(.)
#> [1] 1.5
```

This is explained in further details in: [magrittr and wrapr Pipes in R, an Examination](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2018/04/magrittr-and-wrapr-pipes-in-r-an-examination/)

Comment: I think you can just do `c(1,2) %>% mean`

Comment: yes, but that's cheating! Otherwise I could also do `mean(c(1,2))` ;-)

Comment: ok, I thought you want to use the function specifically in pipe

Comment: This answer is just confusing. The `.` plays no part here. Magrittr can undestrand what you are trying to do if you just do `c(1,2) %>% base::mean()`